# Max per group in sequential order in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the below input:

```
id hid startdate enddate  c1    c2    c3 
1   1       1        2      xxx xxx   28d
1   2       3        4      xxx xxx   45r   
1   3       1        2      xxx yyy   6jg
1   4       5        6      xxx xxx   gj6
1   5       7        8      xxx xxx   to5
```

I need output like this:

```
id hid   startdate  enddate  c1 c2   c3
1   2       1         4      xxx xxx 45r
1   3       1         2      xxx yyy 6jg
1   5       5         8      xxx xxx to5
```

Query developed so far:

```
select id,max(hid),min(startdate),max(enddate), c1,c2,max(c3) 
from table 
group by id,c1,c2
```

Not getting the startdate & c3 columns as expected. Any idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  You can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select id, c1, c2, max(hid), min(startdate), max(enddate), max(c3)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by startdate) as seqnum,             
             row_number() over (partition by id, c1, c2 order by startdate) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by id, c1, c2, max(hid), (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

I'm not sure what the logic is for `hid` and `c3`, but `max()` seems to work for your sample data.

EDIT (based on comment):

To get `c3` from the last row:

```
select id, c1, c2,
       max(case when seqnum_within_group = 1 then hid end) as hid, 
       min(startdate), max(enddate),
       max(case when seqnum_within_group = 1 then c3 end) as c3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, c1, c2, (seqnum - seqnum_2) order by startdate desc) as seqnum_within_group
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by startdate) as seqnum,             
                   row_number() over (partition by id, c1, c2 order by startdate) as seqnum_2
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, c1, c2, max(hid), (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Comment: I want to get the hid &c3 from the last record in a particular window.

Comment: With the above logic, I am not getting correct values for c3. Also, I am not allowed to put max(hid) in the group by clause at the end.

Comment: @Ajit . . . That information should really be in your question.  But I edited the answer to include this information as well.